# usage of Beyond in the sentences and its grammar

Tags: grammar

Check the following sentence and say whether *beyond* is adverb or main verb in the sentence

- *This is beyond the scope of this level*.

This is a correct sentence and I just need to eradicate the difficulty of understanding the grammar of this word.

Comment: Did you see *beyond* classified as a verb in any dictionary or grammar book? I haven't.

Comment: Ok, my previous comment was not terribly constructive. People are expected to do some research before posting a question here. Take a look at [asking in the help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). At a minimum this would mean looking up  [*beyond* in a dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beyond).

Answer (score 2):

*Beyond* is a locative preposition, and like most such can also be used as an adverb.

- *The women's room is located beyond the curtain in the hall.*
- *Humans have travelled to the moon, but so far not beyond.*

In the original example -

- *This is beyond the scope of this level.*

the two uses of *this* refer to two different things, which is not optimal. Let's fix that.

- *These are beyond the scope of this level.*

changes nothing important and avoids distractions.  OK, the subject is ***these***, the verb is ***are***,
and ***beyond the scope of this level*** is a prepositional phrase that is the predicate.

Predicates are prototypically verbs, but there are predicates that are not verbs --

- predicate nouns like *He is **a doctor,*** or *She used to be **President***.
- predicate adjectives like *He is very **tired,*** or *She is really **furious*** this time.
- predicate prepositional phrases like *He is **off his rocker,*** or *These are **beyond the scope***

Nonverbal predicates require an auxiliary verb (some form of *be*) to carry the tense inflection,
because

1. while predicates can be any part of speech or construction, only verbs can have tenses,
   and
2. there has to be a tensed verb (or a modal auxiliary), with a subject, in every English sentence.

Comment: May I use the first three sentences to support a claim that _beyond_'s POS is 'adverb' in that [Humans ...] sentence?

Comment: As long as you also notice that Conjunction Reduction, which is already required (note boldfaces below) will do the job as easily, and thus by Occam's Razor should be invoked: _Humans have travelled to the moon, but so far **they have** not **travelled** beyond **the moon**._

Comment: I suspected it wasn't going to be that easy. Thanks all the same. // Are intransitive prepositions still the way to go with less easily recoverable omissions? eg  'Reaching the ferry in good time (it was already docked – right beside the road to town) we drove **on**.'

Comment: Sure, if you want to. Though I'd say it was short for _onward(s)_.

Comment: Unless the ferry was the intended goal locative. (The problem I've had with the done deal that are intransitive prepositions one is often presented with is that sometimes, it seems that 'adverbs' have less disparate functions.)